# Use a ::std::vector for array creation

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want to grow a ::std::vector at runtime, like that:

```
::std::vector<int> i;
i.push_back(100);
i.push_back(10);
```

At some point, the vector is finished, and i do not need the extra functionality ::std::vector provides any more, so I want to convert it to a C-Array:

```
int* v = i.data();
```

Because I will do that more than once, I want to deallocate all the heap memory ::std::vector reserved, but I want to keep the data, like that (pseudo-code):

```
free(/*everything from ::std::vector but the list*/);
```

Can anybody give me a few pointers on that?

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Comment: Why not just keep and use the vector?  It makes life easy.

Comment: because i do not need it, and memory is critical

Comment: `int*` is not an array

Comment: what memory? Why do you think you save memory by using a C-style array?

Comment: Do you know in advance how many elements your vector will have? If yes, use `std::vector::reserve` and there will be no memory wasted.

Comment: The data is the only heap memory that `std::vector` allocates. The rest is stored in the object itself and can't be deallocated.  You may want to use [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) to reduce unused capacity.

Comment: You're not going to save any memory.  A vector is only a couple pointers so that isn't going to make a difference.  If you worried about the extra space the vector uses because of the quadratic growth of `push_back` then you can use `shrink_to_fit` or the swap trick so it only has the memory needed to store the elements.  You could also just `reserve` the memory you need a head of time if you know what that will be.

Comment: `std::vector` is just something like `T* data; std::size_t capacity; std::size_t size;`, so you just have 2 extra small fields.

Comment: @thejack There is no mechanism for extracting the data used by the `std::vector` such that it outlives the `vector`, other than putting it in another vector via a move. And if memory is critical, `std::vector` may not work for you. I will likely have much more spare `capacity` than you need and there is no guaranteed way to avoid that.

Comment: and if you dont use `std::vector` you'd still need `T* data;` and at the very least `std::size_t size;`

Comment: It's not unreasonable to want this (or something like it) when heap memory is limited. However, you can't have it ;) because the language doesn't have variable length arrays. And keeping the data on the heap but discarding vector's auto-storage metadata is (as discussed) not possible (and probably not useful)

Comment: @thejack *At some point, the vector is finished, and i do not need the extra functionality ::std::vector provides any more* -- Honestly, no C++ programmer writes programs this way.  This is the one of the weirdest cases of "premature optimization" I've ever come across.

Answer (score 5):

In all the implementations I have seen, the allocated part of a vector is... the array itself. If you know that it will no longer grow, you can try to shrink it, to release possibly unused memory:

```
i.shrink_to_fit();
int* v = i.data();
```

Of course, nothing guarantees that the implementation will do anything, but the only foolproof alternative would be to allocated a new array, move data from the vector to the array and clear the vector.

```
int *v = new int[i.size];
memcpy(v, i.data, i.size * sizeof(int));
i.clear();
```

But I really doubt that you will have a major gain that way...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the contents of a `std::vector` as a C array without the need to copy or release anything. Just make sure that `std::vector` outlives the need for your pointer to be valid (and that further modifications which could trigger a reallocation are done on the vector itself).

When you obtain a pointer to internal storage through `data()` you're not actually allocating anything, just referring to the already allocated memory.

The only additional precaution you could use to save memory is to use `shrink_to_fit()` to release any excess memory used as spare capacity (though it's not guaranteed).

Comment: You should mention that not only `std::vector` have to outlive but it must be shure that no modifications to the vector is allowed. Adding a single object can result in realocation which also makes the pointer invalid

Comment: Yes I actually implied that since it's one of the OP assertions, that he's done with the vector at some point. But I'll specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Keep data in vector, but call [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). All overhead you'll have - is an extra pointer (to the vector end). It is available since C++ 11
2. Copy data to an external array and destroy the vector object:

Here is the example:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// fill vector
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[vec.size()]);
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.get());
```

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding and what it does is up to the implementation.